# Is sub-Gaussian random variable invariant to translation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Say random variable X is sub-Gaussian and $E(X)\neq 0$. Is $X-E(X)$ still a sub-Gaussian random variable? How to verify it theoretically?

Comment: This is shown in Lemma 2.6.8 in Vershynin's [High-dimensional probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf).

Comment: @VHarisop can you help explain why this is inconsistent with the answer below?

Comment: @dmh: I took a quick look and I think the inconsistency is that you're using the Laplace transform definition, which is not equivalent to subgaussianity unless $ E[X] = 0 $.

Comment: Thanks @VHarisop, that did not seem clear to me from the explanation in Vershynin's book.

Comment: No problem! You might also want to take a look at Proposition 2.5.2 (sub-gaussian properties) in the same book. Your answer is using property (v) in that list as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\mathbb E[X] \neq 0$ and consider the subgaussian hypothesis, where $\sigma > 0$:

$$\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X}] \leq e^{\lambda^2\sigma^2/2}$$

for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. Applying Jensen's inequality to the LHS:

$$e^{\lambda \mathbb E[X]} \leq e^{\lambda^2\sigma^2/2}$$

which is equivalent to:

$$\lambda \mathbb E[X] \leq \lambda^2\sigma^2/2$$

for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. But this is not possible unless $\mathbb E[X] = 0$.

I'm not sure how to reconcile this with the result linked in the comment above. I'm not familiar with orlicz norms so I might be interpreting the lemma incorrectly.